# How do I specify an escape character for wildcards for Diesel?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I am doing some `name.like(r"A-%\%")` searches with Diesel, but I can't figure out how to specify the SQL escape character I'm using... in this case `\` (so this search is for names that start with `A-` and end with `%` - the first `%` is the SQL wildcard equivalent to `.*` in Regex).

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what code you have, whatsoever. Try to produce something that reproduces your error in a brand new Cargo project, providing information about your DB. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) and [Diesel-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust-diesel/info) as well.

Comment: Please also re-read [ask] and take the time to describe what happens when you use the code that you've shown and how it differs from what you expected.

Comment: Specifically, based on my quick testing, the code you've provided **works**. Obviously, I'm missing some test cases or else you would never have asked the question! This is why it's good to proactively provide these kinds of things as part of asking a good question.

Comment: OK, will do tomorrow.

Comment: @DaveMason tomorrow is over